# is there an equivalent of "show" steps?

Tags: evaluation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get a “step by step” evaluation in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148/get-a-step-by-step-evaluation-in-mathematica)

In wolfram alpha, when preforming for complicated integrals there's a 'show steps' option that explains how the integral was computed. Is there any way to do that using mathematica?

Comment: I assume you don't want to use something with the `WolframAlpha` function, right?