# How to do symbolic definite integral without copy and paste the intermediate results?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

I am do a symbolic definite integral, I am doing it like this:

```
Integrate[1/Sqrt[(ϵ + u)^2 + Δ^2], ϵ] // FullSimplify
```

It gives an output:

```
Log[u + ϵ + Sqrt[Δ^2 + (u + ϵ)^2]]
```

then I **copy** this output and define a function respect to the integrate variable:

```
F2[ϵ_] := Log[u + ϵ + Sqrt[Δ^2 + (u + ϵ)^2]]
```

Finally I can substitute the upper and lower limit to `F2` and obtain my results:

```
F2[ξ - u] - F2[m]
```

I don't like the **manually** copy step. So how do you do this **automatically**?

Comment: You ask different questions in the title and body of the post.  Please make them the same.  It's confusing as it stands.  For a definite integral use the syntax `Integrate[
 1/Sqrt[(\[Epsilon] + u)^2 + \[CapitalDelta]^2], {\[Epsilon], \[Xi] - 
   u, m}]` as described in the documentation.  It will take longer and will result in a conditional expression because Mma will try to make sure that the function is not doing anything funny inbetween the integration bounds (which is the most difficult step of symbolic definite integration).

Comment: @Szabolcs I have edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you would like to automate the process even more, by defining a function that does all the steps in your calculation at once:

```
definiteIntegral[integrand_, {x_, xMin_, xMax_}] := 
 Module[{antiDerivative = Integrate[integrand, x]}, 
  Simplify[Subtract @@ (antiDerivative /. x -> {xMax, xMin})]]

definiteIntegral[
 1/Sqrt[(ϵ + u)^2 + Δ^2], {x, m, ξ - u}]

(* ==> (-m - u + ξ)/Sqrt[Δ^2 + (u + ϵ)^2] *)
```

As the name implies, `definiteIntegral` does the definite integral of the expression in the first argument, but **unlike** *Mathematica*'s built-in integration algorithm, it doesn't get slowed to a crawl by attempting to analyze the integration limits (given as the second argument together with the integration variable).

I took this approach from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30481/245).

Comment: This is best way to do so I think! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
In[20]:= Integrate[1/Sqrt[(ϵ + u)^2 + Δ^2], ϵ] // FullSimplify

Out[20]= Log[u + ϵ + Sqrt[Δ^2 + (u + ϵ)^2]]

In[21]:= F2[ϵ_] = %

Out[21]= Log[u + ϵ + Sqrt[Δ^2 + (u + ϵ)^2]]
```

Note that I used `=`, not `:=` to make sure `%` gets expanded before the definition is recorded.