# Integrating with assumptions and limits of integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have an integration with assumptions and limits of integration. I tried to use *Mathematica* to solve this problem, but I cannot get any results.

```
Integrate[1/(w^4 + 2 (2 ξ^2 - 1) w^2 ω1^2 + ω1^4), {ω1, 0, t}, 
  Assumptions -> {w > 0, 1 > ξ > 0}]]
```

What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: This could be considered a duplicate of [How to do symbolic definite integral without copy and paste the intermediate results?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44643/245)

Comment: I agree with @Jens. All those definite integrals that can be solved by doing the indefinite one should be "the same" question, lest we are going to repeat the trick over and over

Answer (score 2):

Evaluating the indefinite integral works better.

```
sol = Integrate[1/(w^4 + 2 (2 v^2 - 1) w^2 w1^2 + w1^4), w1, Assumptions -> {w > 0, 1 > v > 0}]

(* (-(ArcTan[w1/(Sqrt[-1 + 2*v^2 + 2*v*Sqrt[-1 + v^2]]*w)]/
   Sqrt[-1 + 2*v^2 + 2*v*Sqrt[-1 + v^2]]) - 
   ArcTanh[w1/(Sqrt[1 - 2*v^2 + 2*v*Sqrt[-1 + v^2]]*w)]/
   Sqrt[1 - 2*v^2 + 2*v*Sqrt[-1 + v^2]])/(4*v*Sqrt[-1 + v^2]*w^3) *)
```

If the limits of integration are important, then evaluate

```
sol/.w1 -> t - sol/.w1 -> 0
```

(The second term, incidently, is `0`.)

Comment: @Nasser I don't see anything wrong with this answer. Just different letters.

Comment: @Jens oh sorry, I saw 2 w's in there. did not notice one had 1 stuck to it.

Comment: Actually I want the final limits, w1->infinity-w1->0, and the assumption 1>v>0.@bbgodfrey

Comment: @whdwpy666  The limits you request were not part of your Question but can applied easily to obtain, `(Pi*(Sqrt[-(1/((1 - 2*v^2 + 2*v*Sqrt[-1 + v^2])*w^2))] - Sqrt[1/((-1 + 2*v^2 + 2*v*Sqrt[-1 + v^2])*w^2)]))/(8*v*Sqrt[-1 + v^2]*w^2)`  The assumption 1>v>0 was used to obtain the answer, as requested.