# Step-by-step definite integration in 2D

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, evaluation

Is possible to extend this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30459/step-by-step-definite-integration?answertab=active&newreg=6829dc1254184dd0a53ac995d2c7e05e) in order to perform definite integrals in two dimensions step-by-step?

OK, In response to the comment, I did a try and I have by now the following:

```
 showDefiniteIntegral2D[
  integrand_, {x_, xMin_, xMax_}, {y_, yMin_, yMax_}, 
  form_: StandardForm] := 
 Module[{a, replaceA = "", 
    antiDerivative = Integrate[integrand, x, y]}, 
   Row[{HoldForm[
      Integrate[integrand, {x, xMin, xMax}, {y, yMin, yMax}]], " = ", 
     Subsuperscript[
      DisplayForm[
       If[Head[antiDerivative] === Plus, 
        RowBox[{StyleBox["[", SpanMinSize -> 2], 
          ToBoxes[antiDerivative, form], 
          StyleBox["]", SpanMinSize -> 2]}], 
        RowBox[{ToBoxes[antiDerivative, form], 
          StyleBox["\[RightBracketingBar]", SpanMinSize -> 2]}]]], 
      {xMin,yMin},{xMax,yMax}], " = ", 
     Subtract @@ (antiDerivative /. {x -> {xMax, xMin}, 
         y -> {yMax, yMin}})}]]
```

I think that the former approach could work,but any suggestion for improvement is welcome.

Comment: Perhaps you could try something on your own and report back when you run into trouble?

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to get started in the right direction.

Comment: How can I post Mathematica code dysplaying properly?

Comment: I guess if you did it by hand you would treat one integration variable at a time wouldn't you?

Comment: No necessarily, consider the integrand Exp[-a x^2 + b x y -c y^2].

Comment: But you'd probably have the gaussian integral as a special case.  Another special case is where the integrals are separable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always just compute the integrals in a nested fashion.

***Disclaimer:*** This will not always work! We need to ensure continuity of the inner integral to apply the fundamental theorem of calculus. See [here](http://blog.wolfram.com/2008/01/19/mathematica-and-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus/) for more details.

---

Here's a quick mock up of how to do this, calling Wolfram Alpha to get the steps each time:

```
IntegralSteps[expr_, {x_, a_, b_}, {y_, c_, d_}] :=
  Module[{inner, outer, innersteps, outersteps},
    inner = Integrate[expr, {x, a, b}];
    outer = Integrate[inner, {y, c, d}];

    innersteps = IntegralSteps[expr, {x, a, b}];
    outersteps = IntegralSteps[inner, {y, c, d}];

    TraditionalForm @ Grid[List /@ {
        Style["Compute the integral:", Gray],
        HoldForm[Integrate[expr, {x, a, b}, {y, c, d}]],
        Style["First, compute the inner integral:", Gray],
        Row[{HoldForm[Integrate[expr, {x, a, b}]] == inner, PopupWindow[Button["Show steps"], innersteps]}, Spacer[10]],
        Style["Substitute the result:", Gray],
        HoldForm[Integrate[expr, {x, a, b}, {y, c, d}] == Integrate[#, {y, c, d}]]&[inner],
        Style["Compute the next integral:", Gray],
        Row[{HoldForm[Integrate[#, {y, c, d}]]&[inner] == outer, PopupWindow[Button["Show steps"], outersteps]}, Spacer[10]],
        Style["Summarize:", Gray],
        HoldForm[Integrate[expr, {x, a, b}, {y, c, d}]] == outer
    }, 
    Alignment -> Left, 
    Dividers -> {{}, {False,{False,Gray},False}}, 
    Spacings -> {{}, {Automatic, {Automatic, 3}}}
    ] /. i_Integrate :> Style[i, ScriptLevel -> 0]
  ]

IntegralSteps[expr_, {x_, a_, b_}] :=
  IntegralSteps[ToString[Unevaluated[Integrate[expr, {x, a, b}]], InputForm]]

IntegralSteps[str_String] := 
  WolframAlpha[str,{{"Input",2},"Content"},PodStates->{"Input__Step-by-step solution"}]
```

One could extend this code to work for an $nD$ integral.

Here's a GIF of it in action:

```
IntegralSteps[x y, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I am using Mathematica 9 and by some reason the pop-up menu that display the steps is not working. Thanks a lot for answer.

Comment: @user3116936 Hmm, I just tried it in Mathematica 9 and it worked fine for me.