# How to define a derivative/Variation operation in Mathematica from scratch

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

I am looking for a method in Mathematica 8 to define my own derivative/variation (independent of built-in operations). I do not want to re-define built-in objects since I fear that this could cause subtle changes at different places.

Does anybody know how to define such a "proto-derivative"? I would be thankful for posting a code and some explanations/documentation or a link to some document where it is described in detail.

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking more for a definition on a more fundamental level.

Comment: @user1712223 I think this answer is about the best you're going to get for your question. That link does give some information that would be helpful for defining a custom derivative operator. I think the real problem is that your original question is not well posed, even after (our) edits. I'm flagging your question because of this.

Comment: You might be interested in [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/152).

Answer (score 6):

To start with, give your derivative a name, say `myderiv`. Let's for simplicity assume that there's no freedom to choose a variable for derivation, do your definvatives are always just written as `myderiv[expression]`.

Now all derivatives share the following rules:

- The derivative of a constant is zero

  ```
  deriv[_?NumericQ] := 0
  ```
- The derivative is linear

  ```
  deriv[a_?NumericQ x_] := a deriv[x]
  deriv[x_ + y_] := deriv[x]+deriv[y];
  ```
- The derivative follows the product rule (I'm assuming whatever you derive uses the normal commutative product):

  ```
  deriv[a_ b_] := deriv[a] b + a deriv[b]
  ```
- Using the commutative product also allows you to use the following power rule (for non-commutative products it gets more complicated):

  ```
  deriv[a_^n_Integer] := n a^(n-1) deriv[a]
  ```

Now you have to define the specifics of your derivative. Let's use as example the normal derivative for `x`. Then we clearly have the following rule:

```
    deriv[x] = 1
```

With this, we already can calculate the derivative of arbitrary polynomials:

```
    deriv[3 x^2 + 5x + 7]
    (*
    ==> 5 + 6 x
    *)
```

Now we have to define how to derive general functions. For that, we need a notation to denote the derivative of f; for simplicity I'll restrict it to one-argument functions. So denote the derivative of a function as `d[f]`. Then we can define the chain rule:

```
   deriv[f_[expr_]] := d[f][expr] deriv[expr]
```

We can also define the derivatives of some specific functions:

```
   d[Sin] = Cos; d[Cos] = (-Sin[#])&;
```

Now let's try it:

```
   deriv[Sin[x]+Sin[Cos[x]]]
   (*
   ==> Cos[x] - Cos[Cos[x]] Sin[x]
   *)
   deriv[f[g[x]]]
   (*
   ==> d[f][g[x]] d[g][x]
   *)
```

Now this definition is of course still quite incomplete and also has quite some potential for optimization, but it should give you the idea.