# Reducing a statement with Mathematica, step by step

Tags: equation-solving

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get a “step by step” evaluation in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148/get-a-step-by-step-evaluation-in-mathematica)

I have a list of inequalities combined with quantifiers. And *Mathematica* is able to reduce to simple statement with the `Reduce[]` command , is it possible to see how it comes up with it.

```
Reduce[Exists[{p, \[Eta], \[Theta]}, \[Eta] (p - 1) < 1/
2 && \[Lambda] p < 2 && (1 - \[Lambda]) p/(p - 1) < 
e && \[Theta] (1 - \[Lambda]) p/(p - 1) < 1/2 + \[Eta] && 
0 < \[Lambda] < 1 && 1 < p && 
e > 0 && \[Theta] > 
0 && ((1/2 - \[Eta]) (1 + 1/(e - (1 - \[Lambda]) p/(p - 1))) < 
  1 || (1/2 - \[Eta]) (1 + 
     1/(e - (1 - \[Lambda]) p/(p - 
            1))) < \[Theta] e)], {\[Lambda], e}, Reals]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Probably not... possible dupe: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/148/5

Comment: The link just considers step by step evaluation of differentiation. This is different.

Comment: Did you read the answers further below that tell you to use `WolframAlpha[]`?

Comment: Simply put: no, don't count on *Mathematica* to tell you what it does, step by step, in general. Wolfram Alpha will do it for you, but that's a different kettle of fish.

Comment: @J.M. From the etymologist inside: http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/kettle-of-fish.html