# Is it possible for Mathematica to give the step by step process of Reduce command?

Tags: equation-solving

Input:

```
Reduce[3  x^2 - 2 a x + a^2 - 1 >= 0 && x > a, x] // TraditionalForm
```

Output:

```
(a<=-Sqrt[(3/2)]\[And]x>a)
\[Or](-Sqrt[(3/2)]<a<-(1/Sqrt[2])\[And](a<x<=a/3-1/3 Sqrt[3-2 a^2]\[Or]x>=1/3 Sqrt[3-2 a^2]+a/3))
\[Or](-(1/Sqrt[2])<=a<1/Sqrt[2]\[And]x>=1/3 Sqrt[3-2 a^2]+a/3)\[Or](a>=1/Sqrt[2]\[And]x>a)
```

My Solution by hand:

[image: My Solution by hand:]

Comment: This has already been asked and closed as a duplicate; see: [(13905)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13905/121)

Comment: @ m_goldberg，Is it possible to get the step by step process of Reduce?

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate. Nonetheless I doubt there can be a general remedy to this problem, even though `WolframAlpha` can offer some half-measures. On the other hand certain restricted problems can be easily resolved.

Comment: @ Artes,Can I think that Person's solution is different from Mathematica's solution?

Comment: @tangshutao If you ask anyone you should call him @name (without space between @ and name). I'm not sure what you mean. The problem with your question is that you haven't asked it precisely. Of course you can do much with e.g. `Reduce`, but it is difficult to decide what is needed especially and what can be omitted. In `WolframAlpha` there is the `Show Steps` option, but I'm not sure about its scope. You could perform some experiments and then it will be more likely that your question could find some constructive answers.