# Trace of FullSimplify

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have a symbolic function and I used `FullSimplify` command to simplify the equation given below. I am calculating it by hand but I couldn't reach the same solution. I used `Trace` command to observe the intermediate steps but trace only gives the expression before `FullSimplify`. Are there any possible methods that I can observe the steps of simplification?

```
    Trace[FullSimplify[2 b (-(1/(1 - fd)) + 1/fd) + 
   (2 a (1 - (b (1 - 1/fd + 1/(fd t)))/(a + b)) t)/
   (1 - (1 - fd) t - (b fd (1 - 1/fd + 1/(fd t)) t)/(a + b)) == 0]]
```

Comment: a little bit related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/148/5478

Comment: In general, the simplification methods internally used by *Mathematica* do not necessarily correspond to how one might simplify by hand; remember that a method that is simple for computers to do is not necessarily simple for humans, and vice-versa.

Comment: @Kuba thanks I'll check.

Comment: @J. M. that is true. What I computed by hand doesn't have any similarities with the Mathematica solution. But I wonder if it is possible for Mathematica to show the steps? Or any alternative calculation method?

Comment: "if it is possible for Mathematica to show the steps" - not in this case, I believe.

Comment: What did you get manually?

Comment: I tried calculating again and I think I am getting closer to the same solution. Now, at a point: [(b-2fdb)((tfd-t)+1) -[(a+b)tfd(fd-1) - b(fd-1)]] \ (-fdt(fd-1)^2-fd(fd-1))

Comment: The reason I asked, is that I broke it down into smaller chunks to try the simplify and got a different answer. (I was treating the entire thing as a fraction, which is not how it is stated.)

Comment: @FredKline no there is two fractions one which starts with 2b and the other starting with 2a.

Comment: I put a ( before the 2b and a ) before the / on the second line, which made only one fraction.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To see the full details of what `FullSimplify` is doing you can use the option `TraceInternal -> True` in `Trace`. It probably won't help much though, as it will generate pages and pages of inscrutable output.

One thing I have done in the past is to add `Sow` as a `TransformationFunction`. This shows the intermediate expressions that `Simplify` encounters as it works. It's far from being a step-by-step walkthrough, but you can sometimes get a few clues.

```
FullSimplify[expr, TransformationFunctions -> {Sow, Automatic}] // Reap
```

Comment: Thanks this was really helpful. I actually solved it by hand.

Comment: Nice answer! Great tools for learning more. It seems that some caching is going on by the way, if you don't get the output you expect, give it a good ol' `ClearSystemCache[]`.