# details of the simplifying process

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have a complicated expression:

```
(\[Beta] Sinh[h \[Beta]] + (\[Beta] Cosh[h \[Beta]] Sinh[
 h \[Beta]])/Sqrt[E^(-4 j \[Beta]) + Sinh[h \[Beta]]^2])/(
Cosh[h \[Beta]] + Sqrt[E^(-4 j \[Beta]) + Sinh[h \[Beta]]^2])
```

[image]

The `FullSimplified` of the above expression is as
[image]

I wish to know about the simplifying process (details of the simplifying process for example step by step). How can I reach this goal?

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27422/862

Comment: Unfortunately, I could not understand the process by the help mentioned in the above address as a guidance. The output is very complicated to know what happened!!!