# Substitution employed to DSolve

Tags: differential-equations

How do we get Mathematica to express generally what substitution has been employed in obtaining DSolve outputs?

e.g.for solving particular:

$ \int  \sqrt  {\sin^{-1} {\sqrt x }}dx $

EDIT1:

Context is when sometimes I am unable to readily find a substitution and Mathematica turns up a full solution based on a substitution( when it exists).. naturally I like to know my error or what I missed out by consulting the best text-book answer for the correct substitution from Mathematica. When DSolve does not give anything at least the failing learning student has  a consolation... Look! even Mathematica has nothing in closed form!

EDIT2:

It is an essential part of mathematical communication.Suppose I succeed integrating with a correct substitution (or an integrating factor etc.) and my friend tried it but could not, and on being informed he would like "Hey, how did you get it?" Then I cannot show him only the answer. It appears to me that the *how* part is also important. But I guess there could be difficulties in its implementation.

Comment: *Mathematica* often uses extremely sophisticated methods for `DSolve`, `Integrate`, etc.---ones that do not conform to basic "textbook" methods.  I don't think you can easily display *Mathematica*'s derivations, nor do I think most would be valuable to you, even if you could.  Why do you want to know the "substitution" (assuming there was one)?

Comment: Please search the site before asking: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29363/193