# step by step interactive indefinite integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

[WolframAlpha](http://www4b.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP4111giba3a8036f9ci400000dd961f612c0aiid?MSPStoreType=image/png&s=58&w=439&h=438) can give step by step solution for indefinite integral. There seems to be similar question but for [derivatives](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148/get-a-step-by-step-evaluation-in-mathematica). Is there a way that I can generate my own step by step solution for indefinite integrals (for simple integrals having closed form)?

Comment: If you have an answer for indefinite integral, just take its derivative and you will get the steps of the integration in backward direction.

Comment: @VahagnPoghosyan that's not what W|A gives ... does it?

Comment: Sorry, but I have no Wolfram Alpha. It is not a free software and I can't find a cracked version. I gave you only theoretical idea.

Comment: @VahagnPoghosyan yes i thought of that too ... but if I post that as solution, that will definitely get rejected. I mean I just want to know if it is possible or not. I don't know coding in Mathematica and although I have heard that Risch algorithm is used to find closed solution of Indefinite integrals, so far I haven't encountered myself. If it's not easily done then ... i should give up.

Comment: When I was a student, I used this trick of taking integrals during lectures and exams. I simply took integral by MATHEMATICA, then took its derivative step-by-step, and got steps of the integration :) I think it is possible to  
easily realize the code.

Comment: @VahagnPoghosyan when i was in HS, if i couldn't solve an indefinite integral, i would check the answers on the last page of my textbook and differentiate and construct the answer. But I found it so different from the way it is generally solved, that I gave away that approach. LOL ... it's not nice. But I have to admit, it is equivalent solution.

Comment: Yes I know, it's not nice. Anyway, what is the purpose to write your own code ?

Comment: What is the use of all this? I mean that depending upon your aim one can think of different approaches. Is it for the classroom sessions? Or what?

Answer (score 2):

**RUBI**, the RUle-Based Integrator package, does what you want.

You can download a copy of the rules to use with `Mathematica` at this link: http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~arich/. Follow the instructions to install and make sure that you select the option to "Show Steps". The package's `Int` command performs indefinite integration and will also show the substitution rules it used to get to the final result.

Suppose for instance that you want to obtain the antiderivative from $\int{x^2 \sin{x} \ \text{d} x}$. Using RUBI's `Int` command:

```
Int[x^2 Sin[x], x]
```

[image: step 1]

This has applied one of the rules in RUBI's rule base to simplify the integral. The intermediate results can be simplified further by evaluating them in turn:

```
-x^2 Cos[x] + Dist[2, Int[x Cos[x], x], x]
```

[image: step 2]

```
-x^2 Cos[x] + 2 x Sin[x] - Dist[2, Int[Sin[x], x], x]
```

[image: step 3]

Once further evaluations do not change the expression any more, the last output is the antiderivative we sought.