# Is it possible to simulate a solved example in Wolfram for free, How?

Tags: fourier-analysis, code-request, wolfram-alpha-queries

How we can write the following Formula in Wolfram:

The Fourier Series

$$ f(x)=f(x+2\pi), f(x) =\left\{
  \begin{array}{rcr}
    1 &     & -\pi <x<0 \\
    \sin x &  & 0<x<\pi \\
  \end{array}
\right. $$

**be like as:**

$$ f(x)=\frac{a_0}{2}+\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n \cos nx+b_n \sin nx)   $$

To calculate the following Coefficient (the final solution is mentioned here)?

$$a_n=0,n=2k+1,b_n=0,n=2k$$

> i.e. Is there anyway to wrote above formula
>   with Wolfram Site in free, Or using Mathematia for finding coefficient?

Comment: Thanks J.M,  is there any related tag for my questions?

Comment: You can query *WolframAlpha* in *Mathematica* by starting a new cell with `=`

Comment: any calculus textbook.  (seems off topic here)

Comment: I'm sorry, why angry :)  thanks, I need to do it with Wolfram Site. thanks @C.E.

Comment: May be there is some confusion on Wolfram here. There are three main ways to use Wolfram language: Wolfram Alpha, Wolfram-online, and Wolfram Mathematica. Wolfram Mathematica is what meant by notebook. You run Wolfram Mathematica on the desktop. You can also access Wolfram alpha from Wolfram Mathematica using == method. This way Wolfram language commands are send to Wolfram alpha from Wolfram Mathematica and the answer is send back to the notebook. Most folks here use Wolfram Mathematica. I do not know if Wolfram-online can call Wolfram alpha as well. I myself only use Wolfram Mathematica.

Comment: @Nasser thanks now I got it, so I want to used one tools that give me step by step solution to get above coefficient ?

Comment: [Here's](https://develop.open.wolframcloud.com/app/view/newNotebook) how you can access the Wolfram Language for free *without* an account.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do not use the Wolfram Language at Wolfram Alpha since the syntax is a little different and I have access to Wolfram Mathematica which I prefer to Wolfram Alpha.

If you have Wolfram Mathematica, then you use one of the Wolfram language commands, called `FourierCoefficient` to generate $a_n$ and $b_n$ as follows. (You can try these commands at Wolfram Alpha, but I do not know if they will work as is)

```
ClearAll[f, x, n];
T0 = 2 Pi; (*period*)
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{1, -Pi < x <= 0}, {Sin[x], 0 <= x <= Pi}}]
Plot[f[x], {x, -T0/2, T0/2}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
nTerms = 10;
c = Table[FourierCoefficient[f[x], x, n, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}], {n, 0, 
    nTerms}];
b = Table[I*(c[[n]] - Conjugate@c[[n]]), {n, 2, nTerms}];
a = Table[(c[[n]] + Conjugate@c[[n]]), {n, 2, nTerms}];
Grid[{{Grid[Join[{{"n", "a(n)"}}, Table[{n, a[[n]]}, {n, 1, Length@a}]], 
    Frame -> All],
   Grid[Join[{{"n", "b(n)"}}, Table[{n, b[[n]]}, {n, 1, Length@a}]], 
    Frame -> All]}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And now you can plot the Fourier Series approximation

```
fapprox[x_] := (c[[1]] + Sum[a[[n]] Cos[n x], {n, 1, Length@a}] + 
   Sum[b[[n]] Sin[n x], {n, 1, Length@b}])
Plot[{f[x], fapprox[x]}, {x, -T0/2, T0/2}, Evaluated -> True,PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

By adding more terms, the approximation will improve. This is for 30 terms:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The above uses the standard conversion from complex fourier coefficients to the non-complex ones given by

$$
\begin{align}
        a_0 &= c_0\\
        b_n &= i(c_n - c_n^\ast)\\
        a_n &= c_n + c_n^\ast
\end{align}
$$

In above, $c_n^\ast$ is complex conjugate.

The command `FourierCoefficient` generates $c_n$ and the above converts them standard $a_n,b_n$.

If you prefer to do this by hand, then you can use the definitions of $a_n$ and $b_n$

```
T0 = 2 Pi;
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{1, -Pi < x <= 0}, {Sin[x], 0 <= x <= Pi}}]
a0 = 1/(T0/2) Integrate[f[x], {x, -T0/2, T0/2}]
an = 1/(T0/2) Integrate[f[x] Cos[n x], {x, -T0/2, T0/2}];
an = Assuming[n > 0 && Element[n, Integers], Simplify[an]]
bn = 1/(T0/2) Integrate[f[x] Sin[n x], {x, -T0/2, T0/2}]
```

etc...

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But it is better to use the `FourierCoefficient` command to eliminate making mistakes.

---

Comment asked to show $b_1$ by hand to verify Mathematica is correct.

$$\begin{align*}
b_{n}  & =\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f\left(  x\right)  \sin\left(
nx\right)  dx\\
& =\frac{1}{\pi}\left(  \int_{-\pi}^{0}\sin\left(  nx\right)  dx+\int_{0}%
^{\pi}\sin\left(  x\right)  \sin\left(  nx\right)  dx\right)  \\
& =\frac{1}{\pi}\left(  I_{1}+I_{2}\right)
\end{align*}
$$

Let us do $I_{1}$ first

$$\begin{align*}
\int_{-\pi}^{0}\sin\left(  nx\right)  dx  & =\frac{-1}{n}\left[  \cos\left(
nx\right)  \right]  _{-\pi}^{0}\\
& =\frac{-1}{n}\left[  \cos\left(  0\right)  -\cos\left(  -n\pi\right)
\right]  \\
& =\frac{-1}{n}\left[  1-\cos\left(  n\pi\right)  \right]  \\
& =\frac{\cos\left(  n\pi\right)  -1}{n}\\
& =\frac{-1^{n}-1}{n}
\end{align*}
$$

Now we do $I_{2}=\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin\left(  x\right)  \sin\left(  nx\right)
dx$. Using $\sin u\sin v=\frac{1}{2}\left(  \cos\left(  u-v\right)
-\cos\left(  u+v\right)  \right)  $ the integrand becomes

$$
\begin{align*}
I_{2}  & =\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos\left(  x-nx\right)  -\cos\left(
x+nx\right)  dx\\
& =\frac{1}{2}\left(  \int_{0}^{\pi}\cos\left(  \left(  1-n\right)  x\right)
dx-\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos\left(  \left(  1+n\right)  x\right)  dx\right)  \\
& =\frac{1}{2}\left(  \frac{\sin\left(  \left(  1-n\right)  x\right)
}{\left(  1-n\right)  }-\frac{\sin\left(  \left(  n+1\right)  x\right)  }
{n+1}\right)  _{0}^{\pi}\\
& =\frac{1}{2}\left(  \frac{\sin\left(  \left(  n-1\right)  \pi\right)  }
{n-1}-\frac{\sin\left(  \left(  n+1\right)  \pi\right)  }{n+1}\right)
\end{align*}
$$

Hence

$$
\begin{align*}
b_{n}  & =\frac{1}{\pi}\left(  I_{1}+I_{2}\right)  \\
& =\frac{1}{\pi}\left(  \frac{-1^{n}-1}{n}+\frac{1}{2}\left(  \frac
{\sin\left(  \left(  n-1\right)  \pi\right)  }{n-1}-\frac{\sin\left(  \left(
n+1\right)  \pi\right)  }{n+1}\right)  \right)
\end{align*}
$$

For integer $n\geq1$, the term $\frac{\sin\left(  \left(  n+1\right)
\pi\right)  }{n+1}$ always zero, therefore

$$
b_{n}=\frac{1}{\pi}\left(  \frac{-1^{n}-1}{n}+\frac{1}{2}\left(  \frac
{\sin\left(  \left(  n-1\right)  \pi\right)  }{n-1}\right)  \right)
$$

For $n=1$, and since denominator becomes zero at $n=1$, must take the limit

$$
\begin{align*}
b_{1}  & =\frac{1}{\pi}\left(  \frac{-2}{1}+\frac{1}{2}\left(  \lim
_{n\rightarrow1}\frac{\sin\left(  \left(  n-1\right)  \pi\right)  }
{n-1}\right)  \right) 
\end{align*}
$$

Using L'Hopital

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow1}\frac{\sin\left(  \left(  n-1\right)  \pi\right)  }
{n-1}=\lim_{n\rightarrow1}\frac{\frac{d}{dn}\sin\left(  \left(  n-1\right)
\pi\right)  }{\frac{d}{dn}\left(  n-1\right)  }=\lim_{n\rightarrow1}\frac
{\pi\cos\left(  \left(  n-1\right)  \pi\right)  }{1}=\frac{\pi\cos\left(
0\right)  }{1}=\pi
$$

Hence
$$
\begin{align*}
b_{1}  & =\frac{1}{\pi}\left(  -2+\frac{1}{2}\pi\right)  \\
& =\frac{1}{\pi}\left(  \frac{-4+\pi}{2}\right)  \\
& =\left(  \frac{-4+\pi}{2\pi}\right)
\end{align*}
$$

Which is the result given by Mathematica above.

For $n>1$ we see that $b_{n}$ simpifies to

$$
\frac{1}{\pi}\left(  \frac{-1^{n}-1}{n}\right)
$$

Since the second term is zero. Hence for $n=2$, $b_{2}=0$ and for $n=3$,
$b_{3}=\frac{1}{\pi}\left(  \frac{-1^{3}-1}{3}\right)  =\frac{1}{\pi}\left(
\frac{-2}{3}\right)  $ and so on....

Comment: It's very nice I couldn't vote up because of my points under 15, but very nice

Comment: I ran into a question, is it possible with this software to show the step to step integrals that reach to this answer for $a_n$ ,$b_n$?

Comment: @MichleNiaye if you are using Wolfram Alpha, it has a [PRO](http://www.wolframalpha.com/pro/) version (not free, $5 per month) which is supposed to show step by step solutions. I do not know if it will show step-by-step for what you are looking for. For Wolfram Mathematica, you can look at [get-a-step-by-step-evaluation-in-mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148/get-a-step-by-step-evaluation-in-mathematica) and [step-by-step-definite-integration](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30459/step-by-step-definite-integration) and ...

Comment: [step-by-step-interactive-indefinite-integral](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32731/step-by-step-interactive-indefinite-integral) and [how-does-mathematica-integrate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6811/how-does-mathematica-integrate) and [how-does-mathematica-calculate-integrals](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/111946/how-does-mathematica-calculate-integrals)

Comment: Thanks very useful. one remains question, what is the last formula for $a_n$ and $b_n$ in your answer? thanks so much

Comment: Sorry, I used this $b_{n} = \frac{1}{\pi} (\int\limits_{-\pi}^{0}-1sin(nx)dx + \int\limits_{0}^{\pi}sin(x)sin(nx) dx)=\frac{1}{\pi} (\frac{cos(nx)}{n}|_{-\pi}^{0} + \frac{\pi}{2}) = \frac{1}{\pi} (\frac{1-(-1)^n}{n}+\frac{\pi}{2}) $ and for $n=1$ I get $b_1=\frac{4+\pi}{2\pi}$ contradict in "-" with your table !!! would you please clarify me

Comment: @MichleNiaye your integration is not correct. I do not see how $\int_0^\pi \sin(x) \sin(nx) \,dx$ gives you $\frac{\pi}{2}$. You can obtain $c_n$ in Mathematica using command `c = FourierCoefficient[f[x], x, n, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}]` and now you can find $a_n,b_n$ using those conversion formula. For example `c1 = Limit[c, n -> 1];b1 = I*(c1 - Conjugate[c1])` gives `(-4 + Pi)/(2 Pi)` which is what shown above. It is easier to use complex Fourier series and then convert, since less chance of making errors in tricky integration. ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/B7RSu.png)

Comment: ... be careful, do not plug in numerical `n` values in the integral _before_ doing the integration.  sometimes this does not work. Correct way is to leave `n` as symbolic in the integral, do the integration, then afterwords, evaluate for different `n` values. Either way, I am sure Mathematica `FourierCoefficient` result is correct. If you have math questions about the integration itself, it will be better to ask this at Math forum or in chat.

Comment: I know wasting your valuable time, but would you please show me the calculation of $b_n$ with hand? I means the correct of my solution?

Comment: @MichleNiaye added $b_1$ calculations. Same for other $b_n$ values.

Comment: thanks very useful. I Love persons that love to learn others, I study it now...

Comment: Sorry with your new edit I can sure $b_{n} = \frac{1}{\pi} (\int\limits_{-\pi}^{0}-1sin(nx)dx + \int\limits_{0}^{\pi}sin(x)sin(nx) dx)=\frac{1}{\pi} (\frac{cos(nx)}{n}|_{-\pi}^{0} + \frac{\pi}{2}) = \frac{1}{\pi} (\frac{1-(-1)^n}{n}+\frac{\pi}{2}) $ is wrong, am I Right?

Comment: @MichleNiaye the result you give above, at $n=1$ do not give same result as shown. It gives `+` term not `-`. So it is not correct. One way to check, is to use your $b_1$ value and plot the approximation and see if it works well or not. This is most normal way to check if the Fourier coefficient are correct or not.