# Showing steps for TrigExpand

Tags: trigonometry, wolfram-alpha-queries

If I enter a double equal sign and the following in Mathematica 10:

```
== integrate 1/(1+x^4)
```

Then wolfram alpha allows me to select a Step-by-step solution, which gives me ideas and help on how to do the problem.

My question is, how can I get a step-by-step solution for:

```
== expand cos(4x)
```

Comment: Internally `TrigExpand` is converting to complex exponentials, expanding, and converting back. So a "show steps" capability would need to do it differently, e.g. via the trig sum/product laws. Which is not a bad thing at all, I just wanted to point out that it would differ from the internal workings of `TrigExpand`.

Comment: See [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148/get-a-step-by-step-evaluation-in-mathematica/152#152) about step by step of integral

Answer (score 5):

At a crude level, the evaluator that does the `TrigExpand` can be emulated by a `FixedPoint` or `ReplaceRepeated`. If we want to see the steps behind this particular kind of evaluation, it seems possible that a simple substitute for the built-in `TrigExpand` can be implemented based on `FixedPointList` instead of `FixedPoint`, to keep track of the steps. Here is a simple attempt to do that:

```
SetAttributes[expansionStep, HoldAll]
expansionStep[expr_] := 
 Expand@ReleaseHold[
   Hold[expr] /. {Tan[x_] :> Sin[x]/Cos[x], Cot[x_] :> Cos[x]/Sin[x], 
      Sec[x_] :> 1/Cos[x], 
      Csc[x_] :> 1/Sin[x]} /. {Cos[
       HoldPattern[Times[n_?EvenQ, x__]]] :> (Cos[n/2 x]^2 - 
        Sin[n/2 x]^2), 
     Sin[HoldPattern[Times[n_?EvenQ, x__]]] :> 
      2 Cos[n/2 x] Sin[n/2 x]}]

trigExpandSteps[expr_] := 
 DeleteDuplicates[FixedPointList[expansionStep, expr]]
```

I really implemented only two trig relations here, based on expanding $\sin(2x)$ and $\cos(2x)$. These are applied repeatedly. But to get away with only these two rules, I have to make sure all trig expressions are first converted to sines and cosines. This requires working with held expressions because *Mathematica* has the annoying habit of simplifying perfectly good sines and cosines into ugly $\csc$, $\sec$, and also the less ugly but equally unwanted $\tan$ and $\cot$ functions. So at each step, I first "standardize" the current expression into sines and cosines only, within a `Hold`. Then I apply the trig identities and allow the result to be `Expand`ed. This is done iteratively in `FixedPointList` until the expression no longer changes.

And here are some tests:

```
trigExpandSteps[Cos[4 x]]
```

> $\left\{\cos (4 x),\\\cos ^2(2 x)-\sin ^2(2 x),\\\sin
>    ^4(x)+\cos ^4(x)-6 \sin ^2(x) \cos ^2(x)\right\}$

```
trigExpandSteps[Sin[4 x]]
```

> $\left\{\sin (4 x),\\2 \sin (2 x) \cos (2 x),\\4 \sin (x)
>    \cos ^3(x)-4 \sin ^3(x) \cos (x)\right\}$

```
trigExpandSteps[Tan[4 x]]
```

> $\left\{\tan (4 x),\\\frac{2 \sin (2 x) \cos (2 x)}{\cos
>    ^2(2 x)-\sin ^2(2 x)},\\\frac{4 \sin (x) \cos
>    ^3(x)}{\left(\cos ^2(x)-\sin ^2(x)\right)^2-4 \sin
>    ^2(x) \cos ^2(x)}-\frac{4 \sin ^3(x) \cos
>    (x)}{\left(\cos ^2(x)-\sin ^2(x)\right)^2-4 \sin
>    ^2(x) \cos ^2(x)}\right\}$

Comment: If memory serves, the implementation here is similar to what Roman Maeder did in *Programming in Mathematica*. On the flip side, for `Cos[n x]`, I'd cheat and use the relation with Chebyshev polynomials…

Comment: @J.M. I never read that book - but I read Robby Villegas' "Working with Unevaluated Expressions" which mentions Maeder. Anyway, if you use Co[n x]` formulas directly, there are of course fewer steps to be seen. That may be good or bad, depending on the audience.

Answer (score 0):

```
{WolframAlpha["Expand Cos[4 x]", {{"Result", 1}, "Output"}], 
 WolframAlpha["Expand Cos[4 x]", {{"Result", 2}, "Output"}]}
```

yields

> {HoldComplete[Cos[x]^4 - 6 Cos[x]^2 Sin[x]^2 + Sin[x]^4],
>   HoldComplete[2 Sin[[Pi]/4 - 2 x] Sin[[Pi]/4 + 2 x]]}

Is this what you're seeking?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is two possible answers, not step-by-step solution