# Optimization of recursive functions by using the //. operator

Tags: functions, replacement, recursion

In some cases, recursion in Mathematica (without storing values) is not very efficient.

For example, the recursive implementation of Fibonacci numbers (version which doesn't store the values) :

```
fib1[1] = fib1[2] = 1;
fib1[n_Integer /; n > 2] := fib1[n - 1] + fib1[n - 2]

fib1[30] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {1.500157, 832040} *)
```

Of course, the version which stores the values is faster (but consumes memory) :

```
fib2[1] = fib2[2] = 1;
fib2[n_Integer /; n > 2] := fib2[n] = fib2[n - 1] + fib2[n - 2]

fib2[30] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0., 832040} *)
```

I try to optimize (without storing values and using `LinearRecurrence`) recursive implementations of number sequences $u_{n}$ defined by $u_{n} = f(u_{n-1},\;\ldots,\;u_{n-p})$ where $f(x_{1},\;\ldots,\;x_{p})$ is a function with $p$ arguments.

My idea is to use the `//. (ReplaceRepeated)` operator instead of standard recursion.

I defined the generic function `transformRecurrence` by :

```
transformRecurrence[function_, init_][n_Integer /; n > 0] := Block[
    {index, length = Length@init, terms = Reverse@init},
    ReplaceRepeated[
        {n, init}, 
        {index_ /; index > length, terms_List} :> {index - 1, Flatten@{Rest@terms, function@@terms}},
        MaxIterations -> Infinity
    ] // Last // Last]
```

I use this function to redefine the Fibonacci numbers :

```
fib3 = transformRecurrence[Plus, {1, 1}]
```

Some execution times :

```
fib3[30] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0., 832040} *)

fib3[10000]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.031265, Null} *)

fib3[100000]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.328130, Null} *)

fib3[1000000]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {6.813015, Null} *)
```

An improved implementation (specialized without list manipulations) is :

```
fib4[n_Integer /; n > 0] := Block[
    {index, x, y},
    ReplaceRepeated[
        {n, 1, 1}, 
        {index_ /; index > 2, x_, y_} -> {index - 1, y, x + y},
        MaxIterations -> Infinity
    ] // Last]

fib4[30] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0., 832040} *)

fib4[10000]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.015622, Null} *)

fib4[100000]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.171880, Null} *)

fib4[1000000]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {4.954125, Null} *)
```

In comparaison, the built-in function always wins :

```
Fibonacci[30] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0., 832040} *)

Fibonacci[10000]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0., Null} *)

Fibonacci[100000]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0., Null} *)

fib3[1000000]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.031244, Null} *)
```

And you, have you ever used the //. operator to do such things (even for fun) ?

Comment: For linear recurrences, matrix power-based methods are very efficient. Re: `ReplaceRepeated[]`, I used it [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/89717) instead of recursion.

Comment: I did not, but I have a question. As far as I know, internally any function definition is the application of a definition rule. Consequently, expr //. rule amounts to find the FixedPoint[rule, expr] (where rule is considered a function) and this is exactly what the evaluation loop does (always as far as I understand). So, what would be the conceptual benefit? Perhaps you can clarify.

Comment: @user8074 You're right about the evaluation loop, and the correspondence between `//.` and `FixedPoint`. The latter is just written in terms of functions (which themselves are of course also rules). So `ReplaceRepeated` is (in the *Mathematica* sense) more "low-level", I think. I did a toy example for `//.` in the context of evaluation here: [Showing steps for TrigExpand](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/79648/245).