# Series identity with binomial coefficients

Tags: simplifying-expressions, series-expansion

I have this apparently simple equation:

```
Sum[
  (p/(1 - p))^s*(q/(1 - q))^s*Binomial[n, s]*(Binomial[m - 1, s]*
    (p*q*(m + n) + (2*m - 1)*(-p - q + 1))), 
  {s, 0, n}] == 
Sum[
  (p/(1 - p))^s*(q/(1 - q))^s*Binomial[n, s]*
    ((-(-p - q + 1))*Binomial[m - 2, s] + m*p*q*Binomial[m, s] + 
       m*(-p - q + 1)*(Binomial[m - 2, s] + Binomial[m, s])), 
  {s, 0, n}]
```

*Mathematica*'s `FullSimplify` command immediately tells me that this equation is an identity, giving me `True` as the output, but I fail to see the analytical reason.

All parameters are weakly positive and real, although I do not need to assume anything for *Mathematica* to tell me that it is indeed an identity.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: I don't understand your question. Why do you think they're NOT equal?

Comment: I know they are equal. I need to prove it.

Comment: Or [get-a-step-by-step-evaluation-in-mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148/get-a-step-by-step-evaluation-in-mathematica).

Answer (score 1):

It might help you to look at each side separately.

Starting with the left-hand side

```
lhs = Sum[(p/(1 - p))^s*(q/(1 - q))^s*
   Binomial[n, 
    s]*(Binomial[m - 1, s]*(p*q*(m + n) + (2*m - 1)*(-p - q + 1))), {s, 0, n}]
```

> -Hypergeometric2F1[1 - m, -n, 1, 
>          (p*q)/((-1 + p)*(-1 + q))] +     2*m*Hypergeometric2F1[1 - m, -n, 
>          1, (p*q)/((-1 + p)*(-1 + q))] +     p*Hypergeometric2F1[1 - m, -n, 1, 
>          (p*q)/((-1 + p)*(-1 + q))] -     2*m*p*Hypergeometric2F1[1 - m, 
>          -n, 1, (p*q)/((-1 + p)*
>               (-1 + q))] +     q*Hypergeometric2F1[1 - m, -n, 1, 
>          (p*q)/((-1 + p)*(-1 + q))] -     2*m*q*Hypergeometric2F1[1 - m, 
>          -n, 1, (p*q)/((-1 + p)*
>               (-1 + q))] +     m*p*q*Hypergeometric2F1[1 - m, 
>          -n, 1, (p*q)/((-1 + p)*
>               (-1 + q))] +     n*p*q*Hypergeometric2F1[1 - m, 
>          -n, 1, (p*q)/((-1 + p)*
>               (-1 + q))]

```
lhs = lhs // Simplify
```

> (-1 + p + m*(2 + p*(-2 + q) - 
>              2*q) + q + n*p*q)*    Hypergeometric2F1[1 - m, -n, 1, 
>        (p*q)/((-1 + p)*(-1 + q))]

And for the right-hand side

```
rhs = Sum[(p/(1 - p))^s*(q/(1 - q))^s*
   Binomial[n, 
    s]*((-(-p - q + 1))*Binomial[m - 2, s] + m*p*q*Binomial[m, s] + 
     m*(-p - q + 1)*(Binomial[m - 2, s] + Binomial[m, s])), {s, 0, n}]
```

> -Hypergeometric2F1[2 - m, -n, 1, 
>          (p*q)/((-1 + p)*(-1 + q))] +     m*Hypergeometric2F1[2 - m, -n, 1, 
>          (p*q)/((-1 + p)*(-1 + q))] +     p*Hypergeometric2F1[2 - m, -n, 1, 
>          (p*q)/((-1 + p)*(-1 + q))] -     m*p*Hypergeometric2F1[2 - m, -n, 
>          1, (p*q)/((-1 + p)*(-1 + q))] +     q*Hypergeometric2F1[2 - m, -n, 1, 
>          (p*q)/((-1 + p)*(-1 + q))] -     m*q*Hypergeometric2F1[2 - m, -n, 
>          1, (p*q)/((-1 + p)*(-1 + q))] +     m*Hypergeometric2F1[-m, -n, 1, 
>          (p*q)/((-1 + p)*(-1 + q))] -     m*p*Hypergeometric2F1[-m, -n, 1, 
>          (p*q)/((-1 + p)*(-1 + q))] -     m*q*Hypergeometric2F1[-m, -n, 1, 
>          (p*q)/((-1 + p)*(-1 + q))] +     m*p*q*Hypergeometric2F1[-m, -n, 
>          1, (p*q)/((-1 + p)*(-1 + q))]

```
rhs = rhs // Simplify
```

> (-(-1 + m))*(-1 + p + q)*
>        Hypergeometric2F1[2 - m, -n, 1, 
>          (p*q)/((-1 + p)*(-1 + q))] +     m*(-1 + p)*(-1 + q)*
>        Hypergeometric2F1[-m, -n, 1, 
>          (p*q)/((-1 + p)*(-1 + q))]

```
rhs = rhs // FullSimplify
```

> (-1 + p + m*(2 + p*(-2 + q) - 
>              2*q) + q + n*p*q)*    Hypergeometric2F1[1 - m, -n, 1, 
>        (p*q)/((-1 + p)*(-1 + q))]

The simplified forms are the same

```
lhs === rhs
```

> True

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It is very simple to get the algebrical expression of the simplified lhs (since the binomial coefficients are all the same as the ones of the resulting hypergeometric), whereas the rhs is what really struggles me. And "Trace" does not help...