# intermediate steps of simplification of algebraic expression without evaluation

Tags: expression-manipulation, algebra

I am using MMA do do some algebra and I need to do some simplification. For example, I have the following expression
$$ x^2 \left(  \frac{6 \left(2 c_1 x^6+c_2\right)}{x^4} \right)-x \left( 4 c_1 x^3-\frac{2 c_2}{x^3}\right)-8\left(c_1 x^4+\frac{c_2}{x^2}\right ) $$
Can I get intermediate steps to reach the final answer? For example, I want to factor out $c_1$ and $c_2$ and write the expression as $c_1 (x\dots) + c_2 (x\dots)$ but the terms $x\dots $ need not be evaluated. I can to the calculation as it is simple, but if I could do this from MMA, it would greatly save my time.

I always have some terms that could be factored out. It could be constant $c_k$ or polynomial $x^n$ or trig functions and there could be multiple terms but they are always unique and do not conflict with each other.

Comment: If you write this expression in Mma notation, and then apply `Simplify` to it you get 0. Next time try that yourself.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch that gives the final answer, I don't want the final answer. I want the intermediate step, collect the variables by factoring $c_1$ and $c_2$ so that I can copy steps from mathematica instead of writing the entire step.

Comment: Requests for Mathematica to show steps come up often, and typically the answer is negative; see e.g. [Get a "step-by-step" evaluation in Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148/get-a-step-by-step-evaluation-in-mathematica).

Comment: Try this stuff on http://www.wolframalpha.com/

Comment: If I understand OP correctly, I don't think you're asking (necessarily) to trace out the intermediate steps that Mathematica actually goes through during the calculation, but rather to find a way to break the calculation into steps.  As previous commenters said, the former seems impossible, but the latter is definitely doable, if you're willing to put in a lot of work.    (If you agree with what I said, I would suggest editing the question to reflect this.)  After all, you don't *need* to use any of Mathematica's built-in algebra functions if you'd prefer to write your own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have your expression

```
expression = 
 x^2 (6 (2 c1 x^6 + c2)/x^4) - x (4 c1 x^3 - 2 c2/x^3) - 
  8 (c1 x^4 + c2/x^2)
(* -x (-((2 c2)/x^3) + 4 c1 x^3) - 8 (c2/x^2 + c1 x^4) + (
 6 (c2 + 2 c1 x^6))/x^2 *)
```

for now it hasn't been evaluated to zero yet, but if you try most anything it will do so:

```
Expand@expression
Series[expression, {c1, 0, 2}]
Coefficient[expression, c2]
(* 0 *)
(* O[c1]^3 *)
(* 0 *)
```

One way to get what you are looking for is to change the `Head` of your expression from `Plus` to `List`,

```
List @@ expression
(* {-x (-((2 c2)/x^3) + 4 c1 x^3), -8 (c2/x^2 + c1 x^4), (
 6 (c2 + 2 c1 x^6))/x^2} *)
```

Now you can get the coefficients for `c1` and `c2` for each of the terms in the sum,

```
Coefficient[#, c1] & /@ (List @@ expression)
(* {-4 x^4, -8 x^4, 12 x^4} *)

Coefficient[#, c2] & /@ (List @@ expression)
(* {2/x^2, -(8/x^2), 6/x^2} *)
```

I don't know of a general way to do what you want, but this may work with some input from you.

Comment: works for me with little bit of tweaks!!

Answer (score 3):

I generalize Jason B's answer to group by like terms in any number of coefficients, as well as in cases where you have polynomials multiplying one another:

It sounds like you mostly want `Plus` to keep from evaluating.  You can do this by replacing `Plus` with `plus`, where `plus` is a Flat function (since we might as well keep associativity of addition)

```
SetAttributes[plus, Flat];

expr = (a + b c) (a - b c);
expr /. Plus->plus
```

> plus[a, -b c] plus[a, b c]

Now make `plus` distrbutive (including over itself -- i.e., when it appears in an integer power) :

```
sep = % //. {  a_ b_plus :> (a*# &) /@ b,  Power[a_plus, n_ /; n > 0 && IntegerQ@n] :> (Power[a, n - 1]*# &) /@ a  }
```

> plus[a^2, -a b c, a b c, -b^2 c^2]

Now say you want to sort the output based on powers of a, b, and c.  To this end, I define a `getPower` function :

```
(* operator form *)
getPower[var_][expr_] := getPower[expr, var]

(* Thread over a list of variables *)
getPower[expr_, varList_List] := getPower[expr, #] & /@ varList

getPower[expr_, var_] /; FreeQ[expr, var] := 0
getPower[expr_Times, var_] := Plus @@ getPower[var] /@ List @@ expr
getPower[(expr_)^n_, var_] := n getPower[expr, var]
getPower[var_, var_] := 1
```

(Note that `getPower` requires `expr` to be a monomial in the supplied variables; otherwise the output will contain `getPower`.  Furthermore, note that `getPower[ 1/(a+x), x]` returns 0, but `getPower[ 1/x, x]` returns -1. )

Then you can use `GatherBy` to sort the output by coefficient:

```
GatherBy[List @@ sep, getPower@{a, b, c}]
```

> {{a^2}, {-a b c, a b c}, {-b^2 c^2}}

It might be desirable to convert the sublists back to `plus` :

```
plus@@@%
```

> {plus[a^2], plus[-a b c, a b c], plus[-b^2 c^2]}

You can imagine generalizing the above to pull the coefficients out front.

Note that it may or may not be useful to have given `plus` attribute `OneIdentity` from the start, depending on how you'd like to generalize.

Comment: If I have some more time in the next few days, I might find a way to pull out functions rather than just coefficients.

Comment: thanks, I'll wait for it. Please notify me if you do.