# Equivalent of Maple `ShowSolution` command in *Matematica*

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

While responding to a comment (...solve it by hand quickly) on [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/135643/one-form-of-integration-using-wolfram) question, I used Maple to see all the steps in an integration, differentiation, and limit, like this
[image]
The Maple command `ShowSolution` with package `Student[Calculus1]` in the description states that

> The ShowSolution command is used to show the solution steps for a
>   Calculus1 problem, that is, a limit, differentiation or integration
>   problem such as can be expected to be encountered in a single-variable
>   calculus course.

My question is, is it possible to do the same in *Mathematica* with just one command?

Comment: @YvesKlett That is just about integration only. What about limits, differentitation?

Comment: Check this for differentiation : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148/get-a-step-by-step-evaluation-in-mathematica

Comment: Please also take a look at the related questions, several of  which are quite similar in scope.

Comment: @YvesKlett For each operation, a separate procedure has been developed. My question is a single command which can do all of those in the "related" questions.

Comment: There is a package "Presentations" of David Park which contains such instruments, and much more. However, knowing a reason for this question would be helpful. Are you going to show this step-by-step integration in the class, or is it the way to check mathematical correctness of the obtained results?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch It depends on the situation. But in most cases students ask to see step-by-step calculation whenever I taught Maple. That's why I was wondering how can we do the same in *Mathematica*.

Comment: Wolfram|Alpha can do this: https://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/StepByStepSolutions.html

Comment: @ MMM In that case the "Presentations" is not the choice, since it is just designed to teach freshmen to do on the screen all those operations one can do on the paper.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is asking for functionality that is not supported given the constraints the OP is putting on the solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
WolframAlpha["derivative x^2sin(x)", IncludePods -> "Input", 
AppearanceElements -> {"Pods"}, 
TimeConstraint -> {30, Automatic, Automatic, Automatic}, 
PodStates -> {"Input__Step-by-step solution"}]
```

[image]

```
WolframAlpha["limit sin(x)/x x to 0", IncludePods -> "Limit", 
AppearanceElements -> {"Pods"}, 
TimeConstraint -> {30, Automatic, Automatic, Automatic}, 
PodStates -> {"Limit__Step-by-step solution"}]
```

[image]

Comment: This does not work for everything. For example, `Integrate[x*y,{x,0,1},{y,-1,1]` does not show all steps. I do not have pro version of Alpha, but I assume the command issued from Mathematica and send to Alpha is the same as one using Alpha PRO directly on the web site itself?