# functional derivative a functional

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Can we calculate step by step functional derivative of the following functional by Mathematica?

$$J(y) = \int_{x_0}^{x_1} \left( y^6(x) \right) \, \mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: Did you see `VariationalD`? What do you mean by step-by-step? Do you intend to sort of demonstrating students a variational procedure?

Comment: Yes I saw command VariationalD and calculated it. Mathematica gives step by step solution in differential equations problems, I wonder that can it give step by step solution in this problem, too? Sorry, I am very new in Mathematica.

Comment: As much as I know Mma gives NO step by step solution. Instead, it gives the result immediately. Mma is not a teaching, but a working tool. If one needs to make it a teaching tool, (which is possible, but not easy) he needs to work it out himself.

Comment: related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/148/2079