# Can Wolfram Development platform use wolfram alpha?

Tags: wolfram-cloud, wolfram-alpha-queries

I would like to be able to acces/show the step by step solutions from wolfram alpha in a note book! Is this possible? An

Comment: [WolframAlpha](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WolframAlpha.html)?

Comment: [Get a “step-by-step” evaluation in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/148/5478)

Comment: @Kuba: The answer to the question cited by you is outdated. BTW, the one does not deal with WA.

Comment: @user64494 there are many answers aren't there?, and the 'click show step by step' still works.

Comment: @Kuba: Yes, there are several answers there. But some things have changed to better since 2012/2014.

Comment: @user64494 Can't argue with that, but what is the point? I just linked related question, isn't it related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access step-by-step solutions in Mathematica, type "==" before the limit/integral/derivative request and then click "show steps" in the result. Here is an example. Type

```
==
```

and then

```
Integrate[Cos[x]^2/(1+Tan[x]),x]
```

See the long output [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yaucek9rqhc46xl/Step-by-step.pdf?dl=0) in Dropbox.

Comment: is this the acces to wolfram alpha? are they the same?